# Using JS to highlight menu items

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I know this is a common question, but since I am using Bootstrap I figure it might be interesting for others as well. I have a standard Bootstrap navbar included across all my pages.

```
   <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
     <a style="color:#fff;" class="navbar-brand brand-hover" href="welcome.jsp"><span style="color:red;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-headphones"></span> <span style="color:green;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-music"></span> Martin Music Store</a>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="albumResults.jsp">Album results</a></li>
        <li><a href="songResults.jsp">Song results</a></li>
      </ul>

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li style = "margin-right: 50px;"><a href="cart.jsp">To shopping cart <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</nav>
```

Now I want to style the `<li>`-tags when the uses clicks on them. The one being clicked gets the class `.active` while it is removed from the other one if it was set there. I have tried this code, but it doesnt seem to do the trick:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".navbar li").on("click", function() {
        $(".navbar li").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Probably because when you click on an item, you go to an other page. You set the active class on an object and right after your browser goes to a new page.

Answer (score 0):

Thijs is right, the links sends you to another page.

Add a `return false;` to your JS. But you won't be able to access the link though.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".navbar li").on("click", function() {
        $(".navbar li").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use that kind of css to style hover or focus effect.

```
.navbar-inverse 
 .navbar-nav>li>a:hover, 
  .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a:focus {
      background-color:#eee;
        color:red;
      }
```

But if that page is reloaded than you have to check in which page is it in and then you need to change `<li></li>` to `<li class="active" ></li>`

I think session or cookie can check which page are you in on JSP.